# How do I reach out to a DACPAC project references through DAC api?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I'm trying to use `GetObject` method to obtain an instance of a `TSqlObject` representing a table from a referenced project:

```
var id = new ObjectIdentifier(new[] {"ExternalDb"}, new[] {"Schema", "TableName"});

var table = Model.GetObject(ModelSchema.Table, id, DacQueryScopes.All);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

I've read inside the doc that `DacQueryScopes.All` will get all objects, EXCEPT those in a non-system db.

So I guess this is why this fails, but then how am I supposed to reach up to elements inside that other project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query the object in the referenced project then open the dacpac for that referenced project and query that.

The ExternalDb is a pointer to but not an id of the item you want.

Comment: So basically the executing code must already "know" about a dacpac project dependencies, have access to their corresponding .dacpac files AND load them through `TSqlModel.LoadFromDacpac` method. Correct?

Comment: yes - if you want to enumerate the references to other dacpacs there isn't anything in the API (grrrrrr) but you can use this to read or write them: https://github.com/GoEddie/Dacpac-References

Comment: out of interest what are you doing?

Comment: I'm creating an abstraction layer in the form of T4 template files that will make creating some objects easier. Since there is no form of inheritance inside TSql, I'll code some of my patterns in T4 files, which in turn will provide some cues about objects that are already compiled. I have lots of redundant patterns inside that db (localized descriptions, record history, mandatory data, etc) and instead of duplicating the logic I'll concentrate it inside a template with a kind of "fill in the blanks" approach. It will be much, MUCH easier to develop and maintain.

Comment: cool - I have on my backlog of projects a similar thing but in c# that compiles to t-sql. Will you share it when your done?

Comment: @Ed-Elliott Would your Dacpac-References tool work for updating the paths to referenced database within the dacpac so that I might do a remote deployment (e.g. from TeamCity)? Someone else mentioned that there is also a checksum in the dacpac somewhere that needs to be updated if you go down that path

Comment: Yes, if you use change anything in the model.xml (including references) you can use ModelChecksumWriter.FixChecksum to write the correct checksum (whether you use this or something else to change the file) https://github.com/GoEddie/Dacpac-References/blob/master/src/GOEddie.Dacpac.References/ModelChecksumWriter.cs